# SSRS Formatting a string to a comma number

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following value in one of my fileds in SSRS:

```
=CStr(Fields!Shipment_Weight.Value) + "#"
```

I do this becuase I need the #(pounds) sign at the end. This now does not allow me to format the number into something like 1,000 it gives me 1000 currently. Is there a way to add commas in the code rather than the format box since this is a string now? Values are all different from 1-1000000000

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer it is as follows:

```
=CStr(FORMAT(Fields!Shipment_Weight.Value,"N0")) + "#"
```

That is how you use formatting code without having to put it in the formatting properties box.

Answer (score 3):

As of SSRS 2008 R2, this can be done using **FormatNumber()**, like so:

```
=FormatNumber(Sum(Fields!GrossSales.Value),0)
```

Intellisense shows the following definition:

```
FormatNumber(
   Expression As Object,    
   Optional NumDigitsAfterDecimal as Int32,
   Optional IncludeLeadingDigit as TriState,
   Optional UseParensForNegativeNumbers as TriState,
   Optional GroupDigits as TriState
) As String
```

You can then add the "#" to the end:

```
=FormatNumber(Sum(Fields!GrossSales.Value),0) & "#"
```

Also available under Common Functions->Text in the Expression editor:

- **FormatCurrency()**
- **FormatDateTime()**
- **FormatPercent()**

Answer (score 2):

I believe the above will work, I've always used the following from MSDN

```
=CSTR(FORMAT(Fields!Shipment_Weight.Value,"#,#")) & "#"
```

[The article on MSDN about string formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fb56f4y%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)